# Select inputs that doesn't have value attribute with querySelector

Tags: javascript

I'm using:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[value=""]')
```

But it's not selecting inputs that doesn't have the attribute `value`.
How can I select all inputs that doesn't have a value `''`, and that doesn't have the attribute value?
I would like to do that without jQuery and without any additional function, would that be possible only using `querySelectorAll`?

Comment: That's a bit confusing. You want to select those inputs which have values, or the ones that don't have?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try

`document.querySelectorAll('input:not([value])')`

This should return all the `input` that don't have the `value` attribute.

Comment: That was my first thought too, and only resulted in: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': 'input:not("[value]")' is not a valid selector.` (though admittedly I *did* quote the `"[value]"` selector passed to `:not()`).

Comment: Yes, it should not be quoted.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input:not([value]):not([value=""])');
```

> get all inputs that doesn't have attribute "value" and the attribute
>   "value" is not blank

```js
var test = document.querySelectorAll('input:not([value]):not([value=""])');
for (var i = 0; i < test.length; ++i) {
  test[i].style.borderColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" value="2" />
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" value="" />
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: That gets all the *text* `<input>` elements (a restriction not specified) whose `value` attribute is set to an empty string, *not* `<input>` elements *without a `value` attribute* (which is not what the question asked for).